# Android - which direction does the y-axis go, top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top, in OpenGL textures, Bitmaps and GLUtils.texSubImage2D?

Tags: android, opengl-es, coordinates, textures

Can somebody clear up which direction (top-to-bottom or bottom-to-top) the y-axis goes in:

Android `Canvas` & `Bitmap`,

OpenGL texture y-coordinates (0 to 1) relative to a `Bitmap` uploaded via `GLUtils.texSubImage2D`,

and

Android `GLUtils.texSubImage2D`'s `yOffset` number relative to the above two

?

I have some stuff working via experimentation but I would prefer to know which way around things are before using `GLUtils.texSubImage2D`.

Answer (score 0):

From the very old times, on all screens axis X goes to right, and axis Y goes down.